# How do we install custom fonts on SSRS in AWS MS SQL hosted on RDS

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds, ssrs

We are using the new SSRS option on the AWS RDS, we have to install a custom font for a report that we are working on. I have checked the documentation and we notice that there is only option to enable and disable SSRS on MS-SQL RDS, but there is no option to install custom fonts.

This is the documentation page we had already checked - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.SQLServer.Options.SSRS.html

Answer (score 1):

I signed up for AWS support and requested they make the change, as described in the other answer to this question. They refused and said it is impossible as of April 2021:

> Therefore, based on the above AWS references regarding limited SSRS support on RDS, I would humbly like to answer to your query regarding custom font installation is not supported for RDS SSRS setup as of now. SSRS on RDS supports only default settings on SSRS web portal page.

> Having said that, in case you need to have the above mentioned customization's with respect to SSRS for your application, I humbly request you to please consider the workaround solution of installing the SSRS on an AWS EC2 instance , where you can have Full control\access on the EC2 Host\Windows server to implement the desired\required customization\configuration as per your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

As of today (Oct,26 2020), you will have to contact AWS support to accomplish this. They will upload the fonts to the server.